# iOS AppDelegate add supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if (self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying == YES)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        if(self.window.rootViewController)
        {
            UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController  *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
            orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
        return orientations;
    }
}
```

I try to change screen orientation only one page and i add this function when i start program, program could not start give this error initial screen
Error :

```
2015-02-06 00:40:24.264 AppName[5002:1189245] -[SplashScreen viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d510010
2015-02-06 00:40:24.266 AppName[5002:1189245] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SplashScreen viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d510010'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18269659c 0x192da00e4 0x18269d664 0x18269a418 0x18259eb6c 0x100098614 0x186ebc594 0x186ebc210 0x186ec548c 0x186ec4ee0 0x186ebc154 0x1870d45f0 0x1870d362c 0x1870d1dec 0x18a90d62c 0x18264ea28 0x18264db30 0x18264bd30 0x1825790a4 0x186eb33c8 0x186eae3c0 0x100102560 0x19340ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea ?? How can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to change `viewControllers` to `childViewControllers`

**EDIT 1**: Sorry I only noticed now that you think your `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationViewController`.

It is clearly not as you can see form the error message. It's of class `SplashScreen`

**EDIT 2**: I suggest you do the following and take it from there

```
if(self.window.rootViewController && [self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationViewController class]])
{
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController  *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

return orientations;
```